# Problem with GetDefaultPrinter() over a VPN c++

Tags: c++, vpn

I am writing an application that gets its dimensions from the paper ratio of the default printer of the local computer. This all works well unless the default printer is over a VPN. When this is the case, calling GetDefaultPrinter() takes too long. I need to find a way to put a time constraint on GetDefaultPrinter() and if it exceeds that constraint, break out of the function.

Any possible solutions would be great.

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would putting this sort of functionality into a separate thread be acceptable?